# is there anygood way to write array for mutiple divs and how to show the finial stats of element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <section id="boxBig">
        <div class="box" id="perspective">
            <div class="object" id="seekSlider"></div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section id="layout">
        <div class="stats">
            <input id="stats1" type="text" value="perspective-origin">
            <input id="stats2" type="text" value="perspective">
            <input id="stats3" type="text" value="perspective">
            <input id="stats4" type="text" value="preserve-3d">
            <input id="stats5" type="text" value="rotatez">
        </div>
    </section>
</body>

</html>
```

css

```
.object {
    align-self: center;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: green;
}
#boxBig {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-item: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.box {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background: blue;
    align-self: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
}
#perspective {
    perspective: 0px;
    -webkit-perspective: 0px;
}
#seekSlider {
    width: 100%;
}
#layout {
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    background: orange;
}
.buttons {
    flex: 2;
    order: 0;
    background: yellow
}
.stats {
    flex: 1;
    order: 0;
    background: lightgreen
}
```

javascript

```
 "use strict";

function Gid(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}
var px = 0;
var seekSlider = Gid('seekSlider');
var i = 0;
var stats1 = Gid('stats1');
var stats2 = Gid('stats2');
var stats3 = Gid('stats3');
var stats4 = Gid('stats4');
var stats5 = Gid('stats5');
var stats6 = Gid('stats6');
var stats7 = Gid('stats7');
var stats8 = Gid('stats8');
var stats9 = Gid('stats9');
var stats10 = Gid('stats10');
```

is the any good way to write this with an array? i tried this is one of the function there are ten there mostly the same so i didnt post

```
function perspectiveOrigin() {
    var seekSlider = Gid('seekSlider');
    var boxBig = Gid('boxBig');
    var box = document.getElementsByClassName('box');
    var perspective = Gid('perspective');

    px += 10;
    seekSlider.style.perspectiveOrigin = px + "%" + "" + px + "%";
    var result = 'perspecspective-origin:' + px + '%';
    stats1.value = result;

    console.log(seekSlider.style.perspectiveOrigin);
}
```

so on..and i tried to make finial status for the element ,like status including its rotates and perspective

Comment: so do you want stats1, stats2 etc in an array? and then the bottom function to be able to call each array item?

Answer (score 0):

You could create an array like so:

```
var stats = [];
```

Then you can use one of the following depending on your own preference:

```
stats.push(Gid('stats1'));
stats.push(Gid('stats2'));

stats[0] = Gid('stats1');
stats[1] = Gid('stats2');
```

Next you want to iterate through the array:

with push method do:

```
for (var stat in stats) { 
  perspectiveOrigin(stats[stat]);
}
```

With other method you can also use:

```
for (var i=0; i < stats.length; i++) {
  perspectiveOrigin(stats[i]);
}
```

You'll also need to change your function a little bit:

```
perspectiveOrigin() to perspectiveOrigin(stat)
```

and then in this function change:

```
stats1.value = result; to stat.value = result;
```

I haven't tested any of this, but let me know if you have any problems =]

Comment: var stats=[];
var statz=[];
var i = 0;
stats.push('left');
stats.push('center');
stats.push('right');
statz.push(['top'],['center'],['bottom'])

function perspectiveOrigin() {

  while(i<stats.length){
  for(var stat in stats){
   
 
  stats+=[stat[i]];
  i++; return;
}}
 
  

  
  var x=[Math.random(rgb(0,0,0,1))
  ];
  var color=[];
box.style.backgroundColor=color[x];
 
var y=[[stats[i]],[statz[i]]];
  var p= [y];
  var z=box.style.perspectiveOrigin.equal(p);
  document.addEventListener('click',perspectiveOrigin);
}; 
console.log(z)

Comment: your code doesn't make any sense, edit your orginal post and describe what you are trying to do. =]